# Warning appearing in my various Vaadin 14 apps: Invalid security key received from 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1

Tags: security, runtime-error, vaadin, ipv6, vaadin-flow

When running my various Vaadin 14.0.x and 14.1.x apps locally on my macOS Mojave machine from IntelliJ 2019 Ultimate edition via [Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) 9.0.27 with Java 13.0.1 with Chrome browser 78, I see this message appear on the console one or more times about `Invalid security key received from 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`:

```
[webpack] INFO dev-webpack - Watchdog connection closed. Trying to re-run watchdog.
[webpack] INFO dev-webpack - Watchdog connected.
[http-nio-8080-exec-8] WARN com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler - Invalid security key received from 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
```

➥ What does the message mean?

➥ How do I resolve the problem?

I am using a Vaadin 14 project created by the [*Get started with Vaadin*](https://vaadin.com/start/latest) page. The messages shown above appear the first time I click the `Click me` button created by default with that starter app.

Comment: CSRF token validity is checked here https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/master/flow-server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/server/communication/ServerRpcHandler.java#L257 and exception is throw if not valid. And UidlRequestHandler  catches the exception and logs the warning.

Comment: Could it be that session has expired? The error is from invalid csrf token issued per user, as @TatuLund has described above

Comment: Vaadin is a crazy stuff